# Get Access to Airflow Hooks within a jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, airflow

I have Airflow running using the postgres backend - all fine. Additionally I have running a Jupyter server on the same host where Airflow runs. Now I thought I can just access the airflow hooks from a notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook

mysql = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id = 'mysql-x')
sql = "select 1+1"

mysql.get_pandas_df(sql)
```

But I get this exception message:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: connection
[SQL: SELECT connection.password AS connection_password, connection.extra AS connection_extra, connection.id AS connection_id, connection.conn_id AS connection_conn_id, connection.conn_type AS connection_conn_type, connection.host AS connection_host, connection.schema AS connection_schema, connection.login AS connection_login, connection.port AS connection_port, connection.is_encrypted AS connection_is_encrypted, connection.is_extra_encrypted AS connection_is_extra_encrypted 
FROM connection 
WHERE connection.conn_id = ?]
[parameters: ('mysql-x',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

But what makes me get suspicious is that it not only does not find the connection_id (which I clearly can see in the Airflow UI). It also says: sqlite3.OperationalError - it very much looks like it is not even connected to the same postgres database. I have checked `os.environ["AIRFLOW_HOME"]` which seems to be correct.

EDIT 1:

After I start the jupyter notebook server after airflow, such that all environment variables are set, I get a different error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py in __get__(self, instance, owner)
    351 
    352         def __get__(self, instance, owner):
--> 353             retval = self.descriptor.__get__(instance, owner)
    354             # detect if this is a plain Python @property, which just returns
    355             # itself for class level access.  If so, then return us.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py in get_password(self)
    188                     "Can't decrypt encrypted password for login={}, \
    189                     FERNET_KEY configuration is missing".format(self.login))
--> 190             return fernet.decrypt(bytes(self._password, 'utf-8')).decode()
    191         else:
    192             return self._password

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py in decrypt(self, msg, ttl)
    169             except InvalidToken:
    170                 pass
--> 171         raise InvalidToken

InvalidToken:
```

You can use this dockerfile to reproduce it:

```
FROM apache/airflow

USER root

# install mysql client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mariadb-client-10.3 unzip

# install mssql client and tools
RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg libicu-dev libicu63
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -o key
RUN apt-key add < key
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mssql-tools msodbcsql17 unixodbc unixodbc-dev unzip libunwind8
RUN curl -Lq 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2108814' -o sqlpackage-linux-x64-latest.zip
RUN mkdir /opt/sqlpackage/ && unzip sqlpackage-linux-x64-latest.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage/
RUN chmod a+x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage && ln -sfn /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /usr/bin/sqlpackage
RUN ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd /usr/bin/sqlcmd

# install notebooks
RUN pip install jupyterlab pandas numpy scikit-learn matplotlib pymssql

#RUN cat /entrypoint.sh
# start additional notebok server
# this is a dirty hack but for the sake of this prototype good enough
RUN sed -i -e's/\# Run the command/airflow scheduler \& \njupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=9000 --NotebookApp.token="" --NotebookApp.password="" \& \n/' /entrypoint 

EXPOSE 9000

# switch back to airflow user 
USER airflow

RUN airflow initdb
RUN alias ll='ls -al'
```

Comment: You would also need at least the `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` environment too, otherwise airflow will default to local sqlite3 database.

Comment: Thx! This is because I have started the notebook server too early (before all the environments were set). However now I get "InvalidToken" but I can see a token in `os.environ["AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY"]`

Comment: Is your airflow.cfg file in the same directory as your `AIRFLOW_HOME` environment variable?

Comment: yes, the only airflow.cfg in the system is at the AIRFLOW_HOME/ location